# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'windows' for signature '"missing"'

Tags: r, dataframe, graph

Im having trouble with the simplestR graph. Im trying to represent a bar graph from the `MASS` package

```
library(MASS)
data("birthwt")
race <- as.factor(birthwt$race) 
with(birthwt, barplot(race,  xlab = "race", ylab = "Frequency", label.bars=TRUE))
```

Where I get this error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'windows' for signature '"missing"'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, Jose

Comment: I ran your code and  it runs fine here, except that `label.plots` is not a parameter.

Comment: Maybe if your R version is not up to date with Rstudio?

Comment: I dont think so, I just installed R and R studio  

> R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"

Comment: Then I'm guessing from the error message that you have a conflict with the loaded package `mtable`. Try restarting R and running it again without `mtable` loaded.

Comment: OK this somehow made It but I dont recall loading mtable at any point though